# How to consolidate the sales data using DAX

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a data table named as `sales` in PBI as shown in the screenshot above. I want to create a matrix visualizer to consolidate all the sales by month. The expected output for the matrix will be something like this:

[image]

I'm having challenge to use DAX formula to consolidate the sales. Right now, I'm using `SUM(sales[Sales])` to calculate, but what I got in the matrix for each rows is the total sales. I tried to used `SUMX` as well but it doesn't work either. Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get so much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: There is only one code which is `SUM(sales[Sales])` but it doesn't work. The screenshot is the table. Any information that you need from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it stored as a string SUM functions won't work - which is the only error I can think of with data as simple as that.

You also don't need to make a function for something like this. Just make a new table with "Month & Year" and "Sales" it'll default to using SUM of sales if it's stored as a number or integer.